# Is it possible to stop event messaging inside event handler?

Tags: delphi

I am in the unpleasant situation. When one child changes its state, it calls its parent to respond to this change. In my case, the parent destroys all its children and recreates them. After that the program returns to the point, where the original caller is already de-referenced.

Although I see now, that it is a bad practice and I have to change whole philosophy, but for curiosity is it possible to stop execution on the end of routine?

This is only simple illustration:

```
 TPerson = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FOnChange:TNotifyEvent;
    FName:string;
  published
    property OnStatusChange:TNotifyEvent read FOnChange write FOnChange;
    property Name:string read FName write FName;
  end;

.... form declaration.... 

implementation

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   FPerson.OnStatusChange:=ProcessStatusChange;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
   FPerson.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.ProcessStatusChange(Sender:TObject);
begin
   btn1.free; 
   // and here I would like to call something like STOP
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if Assigned(FPerson.OnStatusChange) then FPerson.OnStatusChange(Self);  
   ShowMessage(btn1.Name); //btn1 does not exist anymore
end;
```

Comment: In a word, NO. It is not safe to free an object while you are still inside an event fired by that object, especially when references to the object may still be used after the event handler exits (which is the case in your example). Events are just function calls like any another. To stop future code from running, raise an exception, for instance (which will work in this particular example, but is not good design in general).

Comment: I edited my question a little bit, but the answer is obvious... Thanx Remy

Comment: You need to change your design, in this example to delay freeing the button object until after the `OnClick` event handler exits.  Such as posting a custom asynchronous window message to yourself (this is what `TForm.Release()` does), or using `TThread.ForceQueue()` in Tokyo+, or `TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(TThread.Queue())` in earlier versions, etc.